# Google Scripts API some events have different kind of Event Id's and they will not pull correctly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

So I am working with some code to pull events by thier id's. With the google calendar i seem to be pulling two different kind of eventId's. The ones that do work are put together like this. 6cs6cdhm6csm6bb6c8o6cb9kc5i6abb274r3ibb4c8s3ephkc8p32c9o68@google.com containing the @google.com part of the id. But I am seeing other id's being pulled that do not contain the @google.com such as 7kukuqrfedlm2f9tg510s8j2dgen8f8f4nojd07m9nopfokpdmrk62gpadccsv8m4c1g. Which no matter how i try and pull the data it brings a null value back for these ones. I am so close to figuring out this project and this is the only think stopping me. I even addded some code you can see below to attempt to add the @google.com thinking somehow it just pulled it without that part. Is it possible it just is not pulling the full id?

It seems like the ones without the @google.com are events that were created automatically like when booking a hotel or a concert ticket purchase.

Here is the code if it will help. I just am hoping someone will know why there are two kinds of id's and how to handle them.

````
function moveEventByDash(finalData,calName,newDate)
{ 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shConfig=ss.getSheetByName("Config")
  var calList=shConfig.getDataRange().getValues() 
  var shLog=ss.getSheetByName("Log");
  var i,j,calID="";
  
  for(i=0;i<calList.length;i++)
  {    
    if(calList[i][0]==calName)
    {      
      calID=calList[i][1]     
      break;
    }
  }
  
  if(calID=="")
  {
    return "This Calender is not available."
  }
  
  var cal=CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calID);
  var startTime,endTime,eventobj  
  for(i=0;i<finalData.length;i++)
  {
    if(finalData[i][0])
    {
      startTime=finalData[i][11]
      endTime=finalData[i][12]      
      Browser.msgBox(finalData[i][9])      
      if(finalData[i][9].toString().indexOf("google.com") < 1)
      {
        
        var evtId=finalData[i][9].toString() + '@google.com'
        Browser.msgBox(evtId)
        eventobj=cal.getEventById(finalData[i][9])
      }
      else
      {
        eventobj=cal.getEventById(finalData[i][9])
      }
      if(eventobj.isAllDayEvent())
      {        
        eventobj.setAllDayDates(startTime, endTime)
      }
      else
      {
        Browser.msgBox(startTime +" " +endTime)
        eventobj.setTime(startTime, endTime)
      }
    ```
````

Comment: Are you getting two kinds of ids for the same event?